# How to use inline function in another file?

Tags: c++

I have the following files:

```
//utils.hpp
namespace Utils {
  inline void saveFile(FileInfo &);
}
```

and implementation:

```
//utils.cpp
#include "./utils.hpp"
inline void Utils::saveFile(FileInfo & f) {}
```

and main.cpp

```
#include "./utils.hpp"
int main(){
  //...
  Utils::saveFile(f);
}
```

But when I try to compile, it gives me error:

```
main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x358): undefined reference to `Utils::savePPMFile(FileInfo &)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [simpletest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/simpletest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I remove `inline`, everything works fine... How to use the inline function?

Comment: put your implementation in the header file (utils.hpp).

Answer (score 5):

Inline functions must be defined in every translation unit that uses them. Either put the definition in the header, or remove the `inline` specifier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have inline functions and still want to keep your header file clean, you can have the implementation of the inline functions in another file (it could be any extension, Microsoft uses `.inl` extension for such files) and include at the end of your header file as shown below.

```
//utils.hpp       
namespace Utils {
 inline void saveFile(FileInfo &);
}
#include "utils.inl"
```

And in utils.inl file

```
//utils.inl
inline void Utils::saveFile(FileInfo & f) {}
```

Now you can use util.hpp in your main program. util.inl automatically gets included to your main cpp file.

```
#include "./utils.hpp"
int main(){
 //...
 Utils::saveFile(f);
}
```

Comment: What about GCC and clang?

Comment: oh I see, you put include in the end... is it a good and clean practice though?

Comment: @texasbruce This should work in GCC. But I don't know how it would be in clang.

Comment: "is it a good and clean practice" - depends whom you ask.  This approach lets people keep implementation in a separate file, which preserves the mainly-declaration "feel" of the header and means programmers viewing the header and wanting to know about the API aren't forced to wade through obfuscating implementation, but on the other hand it's using a file with a vague language-agnostic extension that you could easily forget to include in glob expressions for grepping through sources, might not get C++ syntax highlighting by default in editors/IDEs, might be considered inconvenient etc..

Answer (score 0):

inline functions cannot be used across .obj files .